# Oracle Rest Data Services using java HTTPURLConnection and PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, rest, service, oracle-ords

My usecase is to enable schema and table as REST service programmatically.

I am achieving this via PL/SQL API s .

I am able to successfully enable and do GET , POST and PUT request.

I am using Java HTTPConnectionURL to do these REST request. But I am unable to do delete

sample url to delete a row from DB :

http://localhost:8666/ords/sampleords/employee/?q={"empid":"3"}

I am forming this URL in the below manner

```
    JsonObject json = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("empid","1").build();
    try {
        encode = URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(),"UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String url = " http://localhost:8666/ords/sampleords/employee/?q="+encode;
```

And I am using java HTTPConnectionURL to create Delete request

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            final int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

When I hit the URL I get 200 as response but none of the rows are deleted.
response says {"rowsDeleted":"0"}

I would like to know if there is anyone who tried to access Oracle Rest Data Services using Java.

Comment: Disable the triggers and constraints on the table.

I think you're getting an error where you're trying to delete an employee that has direct reports...or SOMETHING.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just have one sample table and no dependencies.
I just restarted all the setup and database it just worked fine not sure why.

Did you ever work on ORDS with Java before I might need some help?

Comment: I'm on the product management/dev team that builds ORDS at Oracle. If you have questions, feel free to email me jeff.d.smith@oracle.com You can also run ORDS in SQLDev - you can see the runtime log to check/catch ORA- errors on your REST calls that way.